# Module category

Tags: category-theory, graded-modules

I am currently reading about module categories and have been not very successful. In this case a module category is a category with an action of a monoidal category. ([more information on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+category))

In specific my task is to find a module category $M$ over $G$-vect ($G$-graded vector spaces), s.th. the Functor category $Fun(M, M) \cong G$-rep (representations of $G$), where G is a group.

Unfortunately I don't have any clue how that could look like. 
It would already be helpful if someone knew any example of a module category! (So that I can get a feeling for what this category could look like) 
If anyone knows more about this specific example, it would be of course even better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a module category? Do you mean a representation of the category of graded vector spaces?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added it in the question. I mean a category $M$ on which $G$-vect acts.

Comment: Right, that is what I would call a representation of the category (at least with suitable additional structure, such as being additive, but that seems given here). I don't have an idea for the specific thing you are looking for, but a place to start with examples is the category acting on itself in the obvious way.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, that example might be exactly what you are looking for, though I didn't work out the details.

Comment: thanks for the first hint! I'll try to work out the details :)

Comment: okay, maybe I'm stupid aber I can't really figure it out. What I have to show is Fun(G-vect, G-vect) = G-rep. And what I came across is that G-rep is equivalent to the category of modules over the group ring k[G]. That looks easier to show, but I don't know how ... :-( Do you have another hint?

Comment: So first you need to figure out what a functor from this category to itself looks like (I assume that these are supposed to be functors compatible with the action of the  category?)

Comment: The definition of a functor between two monoidal categories includes a functorial morphism $c_{X, M}: F(X \otimes M) \rightarrow X \otimes F(M)$ which then makes some diagrams commute. I suppose that's what you mean with compatibility?

Comment: Yes. The idea to keep in mind is that such a functor will be determined on objects by what it does to a suitable collection of objects, and similar for morphisms. In this case, if you know what it does to the $1$-dimension vector space concentrated in some degree $g\in G$ for all $g\in G$ then you also know what it does to all objects by additivity. So what about morphisms?

Comment: Actually, I may have been keeping the easy example of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded spaces a bit too hard in my mind, since there you see how to get everything from what it does to just the $1$-dimensional space in degree $1$, which gives you a vector space for each functor, and the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ should come from the morphisms. But I am now less sure if this all works out as nicely for arbitrary groups.

Comment: Okay :) I have a few things to think about and you helped a lot either way. Thanks!  If you get sure or have further hints or comments - I am always glad to hear from you or others :P

Comment: Actually, I just realized that this works out nicely here too. We just need to know what happens to any $1$-dimensional space since we get the gradings by acting with the $1$-dimensional spaces of various degrees. So the morphisms are what matters here and are what should make this given vector space a representation.

Comment: I know, that morphisms between Graded vector-spaces preserves the grading. That has to be preserved under the functor. I don't see if that helps, but I can't get it any more detailed.

Comment: It seems like the functors should also be assumed to preserve infinite coproducts, or the vector spaces should be locally finite. Additive functors don't tell you anything about infinite sums.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ahh, good point. I had somehow missed that important detail.

Comment: okay, I've a few more information... Actually G-vect on itself doesn't work here... The category I was looking for is just Vect (action by the forgetful functor). Now I have to show that Fun(Vect, Vect) actually is G-rep.

Comment: The other one wouldn't work because in general $\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C}) \cong \mathcal{C}$.